# Spring Cloud + RDS (spring-cloud-starter-aws-jdbc) failing to load credentials on startup despite being present

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds

I'm using `spring-cloud-starter-aws-jdbc` to connect to an RDS instance. I initially went the traditional `spring.datasource` route, but I needed to make use of read-replicas and wanted to configure this without introducing any weird code.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@47acd13b: Failed to connect to service endpoint: , com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@6f8e9d06: profile file cannot be null]

| at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:136)
```

Initially I tried adding an `AmazonRDS` bean to my configuration and provided the credentials directly, but that wasn't good enough. I set a breakpoint inside `getCredentials()` and can see it being called twice: the first time there are 5 credential providers, one of which contains the AWS credentials I'm passing in via environment variables.

The second time, there are only two providers, neither of which contain my credentials, and so the app crashes. Has anyone ever used this library before and been successful? I can't figure out why it's fetching the credentials twice when I've already provided the RDS client and even tried providing the credentials with a bean.